# Android ScrollVIew Screenshot Size Too Low

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have a scrollview which contains texts and some images inside of it. I need to take a screenshot and share it. I have successfully taken screenshot  but image size is too low that texts cant be read. Need a high resolution screenshot.

**Screenshot code:**

```
private void shareImageUri(Uri uri){
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.setType("image/png");
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void shareBitmapFromView(View view, int height, int width) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();

        if (bgDrawable != null)
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        else
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        view.draw(canvas);

        String bitmapPath = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap,"title", null);
        Uri bitmapUri = Uri.parse(bitmapPath);
        shareImageUri(bitmapUri);

    }
```

**this is how i called the method:**

```
articleScrollView = findViewById(R.id.articleScrollView);
shareBitmapFromView(articleScrollView, articleScrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight(), articleScrollView.getChildAt(0).getWidth());
```

**Layout file if needed:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activities.ArticleActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/topBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/backButton"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@null"
            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/outline_arrow_back_ios_24" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/x01" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/video_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topBar"
        card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <!--<VideoView-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/video_view"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content" />-->

        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
            android:id="@+id/video_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/video_container"
        android:layout_above="@+id/shareButton"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <com.mukti.Utlis.BanglaTextView
            android:id="@+id/videoTitleTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/title_size" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/video_container"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/durationTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_paragraph" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/downloadButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Download"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/articleContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/video_container">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/articleScrollView"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/sc"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iconView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/article" />

                    <com.mukti.Utlis.BanglaTextView
                        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/title_size"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorAccent"></LinearLayout>


                    <com.mukti.Utlis.BanglaTextView
                        android:id="@+id/descriptionView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার ভার্চুয়াল ভাইরাসের সর্বনাশা শিকার but"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_paragraph" />


                </LinearLayout>


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>



    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topBar"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shareButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/app_name"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**This is what i am getting as screenshot:**

[image: Screenshots]

Comment: I don't think you can. It's an OS thing. It automatically compress the screenshot taken.

Comment: The problem you have is the image will only be as big as your view is because you are using `articleScrollView.getChildAt(0).getWidth()`. Also, its not a screenshot, you are saving a `Bitmap` of a view, a screenshot is when you save a `Bitmap` of the entire screen.

Comment: have you tried doing it with a drawingcache?

Comment: yes it doesnt take the whole scrollview. just the visible part. @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: did you take drawing cache of the scrollview, or it's 1st child?

Comment: whole scrollview @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: try taking drawing cache of the 1st child, `articleScrollView.getChildAt(0)`

Comment: tried drawing cache but getting an error when trying with the first child . 
this is a screenshot of my error and code

https://imgur.com/a/2h1OLNM

Comment: calling the method like thhis now 
shareBitmapFromView(articleScrollView.getChildAt(0), articleScrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight(), articleScrollView.getChildAt(0).getWidth());

Comment: how does now your `shareBitmapFromView` look like?

Comment: my code :
https://i.imgur.com/3eyT0hc.png

Answer (score 0):

After line `Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();` send log `bgDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight()` `bgDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth()` and `canvas.getHeight()` `canvas.getWidth()` and you will see that you want to record a large object in a small.

I made this conclusion based on the image size:

```
width: 92px;
height: 1280px;
```

You need to correctly calculate the size of bgDrawable.

Comment: Show size `bitmap` in line `if (bgDrawable != null)` and in line `String bitmapPath = ...`

Comment: and in line `String bitmapPath = ...`